# Default folder location for images when saved as 'wallpaper'

Tags: 2.2-froyo

What is the default folder location for images when saved as 'wallpaper' from an internet site using FROYO or Android 2.2?

Answer (score 6):

The default download location is `/sdcard/download`, I don't know if it's different for wallpaper.  The current image used as wallpaper is stored in `/data/data/com.android.settings/files/wallpaper`.